# Sending report: what should I write at the end of the email?

Tags: email

I finished my report and want to submit it. What should I write in the email?

**My version:**

> Please find attached the research paper.
> I have attached it to the body of this email in doc format, plus an extra version in pdf format in case you have difficulty accessing the file.

I want to end it with something like this: "I will wait your comments."

Should I add the sentence above to the email?

Comment: To whom are you sending this?

Comment: @Roland intership supervisor

Comment: In that case, I prefer to get a feeling for the timeline. Something like "I'm looking forward to your comments and feedback. When do you think you will be able to send them?" and maybe ask what you should do in the meantime.

Comment: I'm skeptical that your question is on-topic. It looks more suitable for https://ell.stackexchange.com or https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Roland "I would be grateful for any feedback or comments " better?

Comment: I prefer my suggestion because it expresses in a respectful and polite way that you expect feedback. Usually, you can expect it from your internship supervisor.

Comment: At a minimum, change "wait" to the correct "await".

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing improper about what you suggest. But capitalize and punctuate it properly, of course.

Comment: how to write in email "i will wait your comments" politely?

Comment: Assuming English: "I await your comments.". You can even say something like "Thank you for any comments."

Comment: what about : I would be grateful for any feedback or comments

Comment: Excellent. Do that.

Answer (score 1):

I usually put a "thank you"-kind like message if the email contains a request or similar.

"Thank you for your guidance"
or
"I would be grateful for any comments or suggestions. Thank you."